# Is an iphone screen not xs sized in bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have the following html form:

```css
@import url(https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css)
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 d-none d-sm-block" style="margin-top:200px; z-index:11;">
  <div class="card bg-secondary text-center card-form">
    <div class="card-body">

      <h2 style="font-weight:800;">Contact Me</h3>
        <form action="" method="post" class="p-3 m-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Your Email" name="email">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
              </div>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Your Domain" name="domain">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Name" name="name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea rows="5" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="message" name="message"></textarea>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-info">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I wanted to hide the form on xs sized screens. However, it still shows up on my iPhone. When I change the "d-sm-block" to "d-lg-block", the form disappeared. How is an iPhone considered md sized? Isn't it xs?

Comment: The given code seems to work with the default stylesheet of bootstrap. Maybe you have a custom build with changed default settings? Or wrong or missing `viewport` meta tag settings? By the given code it is not possible to tell what you did wrong.

Comment: It does work on my desktop machines but not on my iPhone, which is weird. The cdn is the same one as you provided

Comment: As I said it it might be the `viewport` settings. If I test your code in a complete HTML page on iPhone in portrait mode then the contact form is hidden, switching to landscape it appears, so it works flawlessly. The problem is not related to the shown code.

Comment: Thats it! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

#### iPhone size

iPhones have a CSS height between`320px` and `414px` . For more info, visit [mydevice.io](https://www.mydevice.io/).

#### Bootstrap-grid

[image]

*Source - [bootrap-4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options)*

As you see int the table above, `col-sm-*` are for the devices with viewport width more than `576px`.So `d-none d-sm-block` should work unless you have changed the default grid size of bootstrap